# How to NULL output of Taskkill command

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler, windows-services

Sometimes Windows Update Service aka `wuauserv`starts on its own an and starts downloading updates even though I have already disabled it. So I created this command in task scheduler.

```
program: taskkill.exe 
arguments: /FI "SERVICES eq wuauserv" /F
```

But after command successfully completes, this pops up and I have to click **OK** to exit the box:

> "Windows could not start the Windows Update service on Local Computer.
> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."

How do I null this popup?

Comment: Have you tried to append `2>errors.log` at end of your argument? this will redirect errors into errors.log file in your home directory.

Comment: I tried that, but the command won't run and task has a (0x1) Run Result. I even tried quoting the whole Argument part.